# loop record from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table `recipe` contain 3 records

```
-----------------------------
| recipe_code | recipe_name |
-----------------------------
|     32      | tomato puree|
|     16      | potato puree|
|     98      | banana puree|
-----------------------------
```

I want to show records into 7 rows like this

```
-----------------------------
| recipe_code | recipe_name |
-----------------------------
|     32      | tomato puree|
|     16      | potato puree|
|     98      | banana puree|
|     32      | tomato puree|
|     16      | potato puree|
|     98      | banana puree|
|     32      | tomato puree|
-----------------------------
```

I'm using CODEIGNITER, my VIEW like this:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Menu</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php if (empty($query)) { echo "<tr><td colspan=\"6\ "> Data are unavailable </td></tr>"; } else { foreach ($query as $r) { ?>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <?php for ($a=1 ; $a <=7 ; $a++) { ?>
      <td>
        <?php echo $a; ?>
      </td>
      <?php ?>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . " index.php/home/view_recipe/ " . $r->code_recipe; ?>">
          <?php echo $r->recipe_name; ?></a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <?php } } ?>
</table>
<?php }
```

Result :

```
---------------------
| Day | recipe_name |
---------------------
|  1  | tomato puree|
|  2  | tomato puree|
|  3  | tomato puree|
|  4  | tomato puree|
|  5  | tomato puree|
|  6  | tomato puree|
|  7  | tomato puree|
|  1  | potato puree|
|  2  | potato puree|
|  3  | potato puree|
|  4  | potato puree|
|  5  | potato puree|
|  6  | potato puree|
|  7  | potato puree|
|  1  | banana puree|
|  2  | banana puree|
|  3  | banana puree|
|  4  | banana puree|
|  5  | banana puree|
|  6  | banana puree|
|  7  | banana puree|
---------------------
```

please help me

Comment: 2 results? or only the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your `foreach()` loop inside your `7` loop. Try something like this, using a while loop.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Menu</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php 
  if (empty($query)) { echo "<tr><td colspan=\"6\"> Data are unavailable </td></tr>"; } 
  else { 
   $a=1;
   while($a <=7){ 
    foreach ($query as $r){
      if($a>7)break; // if over 7 break out of loop ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $a; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . " index.php/home/view_recipe/ " . $r->code_recipe; ?>">
          <?php echo $r->recipe_name; ?></a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  <?php 
    $a++; // increase $a
   } } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php }
```